# Why is execvp() executing twice using fork()?

Tags: c, linux, bash, fork

I am implementing a shell.

When attempting a command other than changing directories, `execvp()` runs, the child terminates and a new child is created. When I change directories, the child does not terminate and a new child is created. Here is a sample of my code:

```
for(;;) {
    printf("bash: ");
    parse();
    ...
    pid_t pid = fork()
    if (pid == 0)
        if (!strcmp(line[0], "cd"))
            if (!line[1]) (void) chdir(getenv("HOME"));
            else (void) chdir(line[1]);
        else execvp(line[0], line);
    ...
    if (pid > 0) {
        while (pid == wait(NULL));
        printf("%d terminated.\n", pid);
    }
}
```

`cd ../; ls;` runs correctly, except I have to `Ctrl+D` twice to end the program.

Though, if I pipe the same information (ie. `mybash < chdirtest`), it runs correctly once, terminates the child, runs again except in the original directly, then terminates the final child.

Comment: When you run `cd` the (incomplete) code as show will not invoke `execvp`. Instead it will do the `chdir` and then continue to run the next `for` loop iteration which will invoke `fork`. That's why the first child process does not exit for the `cd` case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  My immediate take is that there isn't enough information here for us to be able to answer — the devil is in the details, and the details are missing.  However, @kaylum is onto at least part of the problem, and probably has identified the main trouble. (I'll observe that the conditionals after `if (pid == 0)` petrify me — not enough braces, and no error handling if the `execvp()` or `chdir()` fails.)  Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) and then provide one.

Comment: @kaylum I do not want `cd` to invoke `execvp()`. I want it to change the directory, loop back, then run the next line without the issues stated.

Comment: Fine, but your question is why does the child not exit. And that's an attempt at an explanation why. If you don't think that explanation is correct then do point out why. If you don't want it to fork again then the `cd` case should call `chdir` and then continue with parsing and execing the next command without another `fork`.

Comment: "creating a bash program" No, you're implementing a shell (possibly similar to bash)

Comment: @DanielJour My apologies. Fixed.

Comment: Your tabulation is incorrect, which misleads you/us/everyone. Please put all blocks in curly braces (`{}`) first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cd` should not be invoked through a child process, the shell itself should change its current directory (that's the property of an internal command: modify the process of the shell itself).

A (primitve) shell should looks like:

```
for(;;) {
    printf("bash: ");
    parse();

    // realize internal commands (here "cd")
    if (!strcmp(line[0], "cd")) {
       if (!line[1]) (void) chdir(getenv("HOME"));
       else (void) chdir(line[1]);
       continue; // jump back to read another command
    }

    // realize external commands
    pid_t pid = fork()
    if (pid == 0) {
        execvp(line[0], line);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // wrong exec
    }

    // synchro on child
    if (pid > 0) {
        while (pid == wait(NULL));
        printf("%d terminated.\n", pid);
    }
}
```